# Transitive/nested permissions in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have the following setup:

```sql
create role test_user noinherit nologin;

create table test_me ( attr text );
create view v_test_me as select * from test_me;

create function fn() returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    insert into test_me(attr) values (NEW.attr);
    return NEW;
end; $$;
create trigger tg instead of insert on v_test_me 
for each row execute procedure fn();

grant insert on v_test_me to test_user;

set role test_user;
insert into v_test_me(attr) values ('hello?');
```

Here I have a table and a view on top of it. The view has an instead-of-trigger. I am allowing `test_user` to insert into the view. But i get the following error:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for table test_me
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "insert into test_me(attr) values (NEW.attr)"
```

It looks like I do not have permission to execute an `insert` statement on the `test_me` table, which is expected. Is there any way I can allow user to insert into `test_me` table without directly granting them such permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case a `SECURITY DEFINER` modifier on the trigger function `fn()` will solve the issue. As per [`CREATE FUNCTION` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createfunction.html):

> `SECURITY DEFINER` specifies that the function is to be executed with
>   the privileges of the user that created it

This will allow inserting into `test_me` table, provided the owner of the function has such permission.

Comment: Heed the warning in the documentation and set `search_path` on all `SECURITY DEFINER` functions.